# jQuery UI Position right top set's CSS to left top

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

This code :

```
controls.position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right top",
    of: parent
});
```

is setting the element `controls` CSS as

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 1355px;">...</div>
```

Why does it not set it as `right: 0px;` ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the code is compatible with older browsers which don't support the `right` or `bottom` CSS properties. Older IE's don't support those.

Comment: I don't know... there's nothing in the code proving that assumption. All I see is that they only calculate `position.left` and `position.right`.